# PTIJ: All Sukkahs that are Kosher are also Passul?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

If a Sukkah needs [פסולת](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A4%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%AA) (raw organic material that can't be Mekabel Tumah and is detached from the ground) for the Schach to be Kosher, then doesn't every Kosher Sukkah have Passul-ness to it?

Which means every Kosher Sukkah has P'soles (Pasul material)? So then a Sukkah is both Kosher and Passul at the same time.

(This sounds like the Parah Adumah, making those Tahor Tamei, and those Tamei Tahor.)

[image: Kosher and Passul Sukkah]

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/120324/why-was-shaatnez-used-in-making-the-mishkan

Answer (score 4):

פסולת is a defective spelling of the actual word, פסול**י**ת, which decomposes in to פסול **לית**, meaning there is no פסול. I'm shocked that this misconception has endured for so long.

Answer (score 1):

The Ketores requires Chelbana, an unpleasant smelling spice. The reason is by blending in this unpleasant smell, the final scent is more pleasant.

A Sucah also needs some Passul Ness in order to make it more Kosher.

Answer (score 1):

All kosher succos are passul because the *shechinah* rests on the succah, which is why the Zohar says that the succah is *tzila di'mehemnusa* - the shade of belief.

The *shechinah* has infinite energy, so once the *shechinah* is *shoreh* in the succah, the succah is vaporised and ceases to exist. Once the succah ceases to exist it becomes passul and the *shechinah* is *nistalek*. Hence it becomes a kosher succah again u.s.w.

So you could ask a *kashye* on the above *peshat*:

Surely when the succah exists it is kosher and when it does not exist there is no *sechach* for us to say that the *sechach* is not *me'sacheach*?

This is not *schwer* because there is a slight lag when the succah comes back into existence in which the succah exists but has not yet become kosher. Some say this is because it is not clear in which order the various parts of the succah materialise and others say this is because a *chalos* takes a finite time to be *chal*.

*Ve'divrei pi chacham chein*.

Comment: So, like the refresh rate of physics?

Comment: @Moshe It has to do with string theory.